# What is Niska's accent?

Tags: firefly, accent

Mr Niska is a 'recurring' (stars in 2 of 14 episodes) antagonist in *Firefly*, an old man with a mini empire and a penchant for torture. He's very creepy and has a very distinctive accent, which I always thought sounded Russian, but I'm not always good with accents.

**What is the accent used for Mr Niska in *Firefly*?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Niska speaks **Czech** to one of his flunkies

> Dej jim za to plátek masa

This translates to "*Give them a slice of meat*"

This is backed up by the [shooting script](http://www.myths.com/pub/tv/firefly/script-war-stories.html)

> **NISKA:** *No, no, no. I insist.*
> (to Torturer, in Czech) They have enough for a slice.
> (to Zoe, in English) I wouldn't want the talk to be that Adelai Niska is a cheat.

and official [Firefly RPG Corebook](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/128012/Firefly-RolePlaying-Game-Corebook)

> **ADELAI NISKA**
>
> Mr. Adelai Niska is a wealthy crime boss with a passel of
> Scary-Looking Henchmen, a torturer, and a fortified
> skyplex to call his own. Unlike Badger, Niska is overflowing with
> charm and is accustomed to playing the part of a fine, elderly
> gentleman. One might even say he’s downright philosophical.
> T**he Georgia System’s notorious gangster is fluent in both
> Chinese and Czech, at the helm of a close-knit family, and
> proudly displays a few Earth-That-Was artifacts.** His polite,
> grandfatherly demeanor fools a lot of folk. Underneath it all,
> Niska is a criminal mastermind obsessed with protecting his
> fierce reputation.

In the *[Serenity RPG Big Damn Heroes Supplement](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1931567824)*, his accent is referred to as "*Slavic*"

> Niska’s voice is soft and **he speaks with a Slavic accent**.

It seems likely given his Earth-That-Was ties and closely knit family links, that Niska's people originally came from the Eastern European region, hence the preservation of a strong and distinctive Slavic accent.

Comment: This is interesting information, but doesn't necessarily answer the question of his accent when speaking English.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - The fact that he and his henchman speak Czech to each other *in private* would strongly suggest (when coupled with his heavy slavic accent) that this is his primary language.

Comment: Yup, this is pretty confirmatory evidence that he comes from a Czech background in-universe. I'd still be curious if that fits his actual accent in the series. (For example - pure speculation - it's possible that the actor didn't know a Czech accent specifically and just did a Russian or Polish one, assuming that Slavic accents are all similar enough.)